# Can't disable debug/backtrace on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, debugging

I was encountering an error sending email so I turned on the backtrace/enabled debugging. No I can't get back to the menu to turn it off. I just have a page of error messages.

Help! Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks
Caroline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have command-line access and [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org) enabled (with the CiviCRM extension), you can run: `wp civicrm disable-debug`.

If you don't have command-line access, run the following SQL via PHPMyAdmin or similar:

`UPDATE civicrm_setting SET value = 'i:0;' WHERE name = 'backtrace' OR name = 'debug_enabled';`